# Ajax Php Charts

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, charts

I'm new to charts in php and Jquery. I have a table in mysql name students with a field 'gender'. I want to take a percentage of each of the two gender (Male and Female) over the total and represent it in a doughnut chart as percentage. I have the following codes but not working.

php

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');

define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'siloam');

$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

if(!$mysqli){
    die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->error);
}


$query=sprintf(
    "select gender,
            gender * 100
                / (SELECT SUM(gender)
                   FROM   students
                   WHERE  gender = 'Male')
            AS male_percent
     from   students AND gender * 100
                / (SELECT SUM(gender)
                   FROM   students
                   WHERE  gender = 'Female')
            AS female_percent
     from   students ");

$result = $mysqli->query($query);


$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
}


$result->close();

//close connection
$mysqli->close();

print json_encode($data);
```

Js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url : "data.php",
        type : "GET",
        success : function(data) {

            console.log(data);

            var ctx1 = $("#doughnut-chartcanvas-1");

            var data1 = {
                labels : ["Male", "Female""],
                datasets : [
                    {
                        label : "gender",
                        data : data,
                        backgroundColor : [
                            "#DEB887",
                            "#A9A9A9"

                        ],
                        borderColor : [
                            "#CDA776",
                            "#989898"

                        ],
                        borderWidth : [1,1]
                    }
                ]
            };



            var options1 = {
                title : {
                    display : true,
                    position : "top",
                    text : "Percentage of Students Per Gender",
                    fontSize : 18,
                    fontColor : "#111"
                },
                legend : {
                    display : true,
                    position : "bottom"
                }
            };


            var chart1 = new Chart( ctx1, {
                type : "doughnut",
                data : data1,
                options : options1
            } );



        },
        error : function(data) {

            console.log(data);

        }
    });

});
```

html

```
<div class="chart-container">
<div class="doughnut-chart-container">
<canvas id="doughnut-chartcanvas-1"></canvas>
</div>
</div>
```

Is there any better way to do this, or may be how to fix the codes, please someone help.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I just don't get the chart, the div show nothing,